catelog sentences into 5 words that represent them
I have dataframe with 1000 text rows. df['text']
I also have 5 words that I want to know for each one of them how much they represnt the text  (between 0 to 1)
every score will be in df["word1"] ,df["word2"] and etc
I will glad for recomendations how to do that
edit
represnt = the semantic distance between the word to the text.
for example -
lets say in row 1 the text is "i want to eat"
and I have 2 words : food and house.
so in df["food "] it would be higher score than in df["house"]

What do you mean by "how much they represent the text" ? the number of times the word is in the text?

the semantic distance between the word to the text.

Is it a programming question? if so please show what you tried, if not use an embedding pretrained model to transform each text/word into vectors and compute cosine similarity between each text and each 5 words.

You could use a pre-trained sentence transformer model from sentence_transformers:
import pandas as pd
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util


class SemanticSimilarityCalculator:
  def __init__(self, model_name: str = 'all-MiniLM-L6-v2') -> None:
    self.model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)
    self.word_embeddings = None

  def encode_words(self, words: list[str]) -> None:
    self.word_embeddings = self.model.encode(words, convert_to_tensor=True)
    self.words = words

  def calculate_similarity(self, text: str) -> list[float]:
    if self.word_embeddings is None:
      raise ValueError('Words must be encoded before calculating similarity.')
    text_embedding = self.model.encode(text, convert_to_tensor=True)
    similarities = util.cos_sim(text_embedding, self.word_embeddings)[
      0
    ].tolist()
    return similarities

  def add_similarity_scores_to_df(
    self, df: pd.DataFrame, text_column: str
  ) -> pd.DataFrame:
    if self.words is None:
      raise ValueError(
        'Words must be encoded before adding scores to the DataFrame.'
      )
    similarity_columns = ['word_' + word for word in self.words]
    df[similarity_columns] = df[text_column].apply(
      lambda text: pd.Series(self.calculate_similarity(text))
    )
    return df


def main():
  data = {'text': ['I want to eat', 'The house is big', 'I need to sleep']}
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  words = ['food', 'house', 'sleep', 'drink', 'run']
  calculator = SemanticSimilarityCalculator()
  calculator.encode_words(words)
  df_with_scores = calculator.add_similarity_scores_to_df(
    df, text_column='text'
  )
  print(df_with_scores)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Output:
               text  word_food  word_house  word_sleep  word_drink  word_run
0     I want to eat   0.592410    0.215032    0.254065    0.370329  0.259350
1  The house is big   0.243262    0.672110    0.170785    0.213780  0.119716
2   I need to sleep   0.253703    0.222462    0.725105    0.358372  0.303838

